# Failed to start Redis Datastore Server (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)

Tags: services, redis

i just installed redis and it doesnt work at all when trying to start service with command:

`sudo service redis-server start`

this is result of `journalctl -xe`:

```
Subject: Unit redis-server.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit redis-server.service has finished shutting down.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis Datastore Server.
```

and this is the result of `systemctl status redis-server.service`:

```
 redis-server.service - Redis Datastore Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead) (Result: resources) since Kam 2017-03-02 13:22:46 WIB; 5min ago
 Process: 12120 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis Datastore Server.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaaaa-notebook systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: Stopped Redis Datastore Server.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 02 13:22:46 aaa-notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis Datastore Server.
```

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and could not find a working solution anywhere. After some searching, the following fix worked for me ( Ubuntu 16.04 )

In */etc/systemd/system/redis.service* add the following under the `[Service]` section.

```
Type=forking
```

Comment: Mine too, thanks! How did you discover to add this? What does it actually do?

Answer (score 8):

Open your service using whatever editor.

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
```

Look at your `[Service]` section at `ExecStart` mine was:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Run this command to see what errors are occuring. Mine responded with this:

```
 Fatal error, can't open config file '/etc/redis/redis.conf'
```

So I just updated that line to this (where my actual config file was)

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/6379.conf
```

Which is where redis quickstart places it by default... :)

Answer (score 8):

In my case , the log directory (`/var/log/redis`) which I mention in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file was not present

How I find the error

Try

```
/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

This is same command present in my `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` file

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Solution

1) Create the log directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/redis
```

2) Give proper access to create and write logs

```
sudo chown redis:redis /var/log/redis
```

Try to start the service again

```
sudo service redis-server start
```

or

```
sudo service redis start
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I screwed myself up by deleting everything in the log file and I suffered so much and spent hours and hours fixing all the programs :D

Answer (score 2):

redis.service file is missing in "/etc/systemd/system/" directory

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/redis.service

then copy and paste these lines

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

save and close this file

next modify the directory permisssions

```
$ sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home redis
$ sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis
$ sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis
```

next start the redis server

> $ sudo systemctl start redis

check if its running now

> $ sudo systemctl status redis

REFERENCE : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. But for me the reason was totally different: It was due to a typo in my `redis.conf` file. Correcting that and doing `sudo systemctl restart redis-server` restarted redis instantly. It is misleading that same error is being thrown for this case also.

Answer (score 1):

after making all conf try these commands

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis

sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis
```

And after

```
sudo systemctl start redis
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `redis.log`. You should see something like this:

```
41393:M 07 Jun 17:02:19.034 # You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
41393:M 07 Jun 17:02:19.034 # Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
41393:M 07 Jun 17:02:19.034 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
41393:M 07 Jun 17:02:19.034 # Can't open the append-only file: Read-only file system
```

Therefore check your system limits and maybe file permissions of your `redis` AOF (`/var/lib/redis/*`). For system limits, here is a [good guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39506150/1073606).

Answer (score 0):

I needed both a /var/lib/redis folder and a redis user and group.

I used Kevin Upton's https://askubuntu.com/a/981641/451682 advice to find my issues: `vim /etc/systemd/system/redis.service` led me to  `/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf` which responded with `Can't chdir to '/var/lib/redis': No such file or directory` which I created with `sudo mkdir /var/lib/redis`.

Then, though, I also needed to create the redis user and group and plop that on the /var/lib/redis dir, following Rishik Rohan's https://askubuntu.com/a/918408/451682 :

```
sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home redis
sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis
sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis
```

Thanks you two!

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve that issue:-
+==============+
A. Set memory limit in redis.conf in 566 number line

566 maxmemory 256mb
567 maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru

B. set the Linux kernel overcommit memory setting to 1:

$ sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1

or /etc/sysctl.conf and change it to 1.

C. Restart the redis server now.

$ systemctl restart redis

Please check now Redis status.

And if the still issue persists then Go and edit and redis service file.

=========
vi /etc/systemd/system/redis.service

You will see like this:-

[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

## Type=Forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Change it
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

to

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf

Now, Start the redis service

$ systemctl start redis

Now Redis will start without giving any error.

+==============+

Testing the redis:-

[root@server]# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
Use the echo command to echo a given string:
127.0.0.1:6379> echo "Tecmint is testing Redis"
You can also set a key value using the set command like this:
127.0.0.1:6379> set mykey "is testing Redis"
Now view the value of mykey:
127.0.0.1:6379> get mykey
"is testing Redis"
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
[root@server]#

Now redis started successfully and running.

+==================+

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Although Even rebooting the system could not help, in my case it was because of a running background process which was found using :

`ss -tulpn`

killed it.

`kill [process id/number]`

Afterwards I could start redis service again.

`service redis start`

Comment: I do not see how this answer works with the question ...

Answer (score 0):

When updating from versions <6 to 6 and above, systemd support has been added in by default.

But your old config might have an old setting `supervised = no` inside.

That won't work with the `Systemd Service` Type **notify**.

Set the option `supervised = systemd` in your (`/etc/redis/redis-conf`) redis.conf and it should work.